# can't use member outside resource(s) scope (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have this code in my routes.db file:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
```

and I get the error:

```
can't use member outside resource(s) scope (ArgumentError)
```

How do I fix this?

UPDATE: here's all the code to my routes.db file:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
get "sessions/new"

resources :users
member do
  get :following, :followers
end

resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :microposts, :only => [:create, :destroy]
resources :relationships, :only => [:create, :destroy]

match '/signup', :to => 'users#new' 
match '/signin',  :to => 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy' 

match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'

root :to => 'pages#home'
```

Comment: Is that the _only_ code in your routes.rb file?

Comment: nope, just reproduced all the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code you have the following:

```
resources :users
member do
  get :following, :followers
end
```

which means you are missing a do statement and an end statement for your resources declaration, change it to this:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
```

Also, you are missing a final end for the Application.routes.draw do statement.